# How to prevent Google Chrome from installing Docs, Sheets, and Slides apps on every update?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-docs

These apps appear in the Launchpad and Application folder.

As I understand, these are just bookmarks. But it’s really annoying to delete them each time.

I've tried to delete them from the `chrome://apps/`, but they appear again after the next Chrome update.

Is there a way to prevent Google to install these apps into Launchpad and Google Chrome apps?

[image]

Comment: reveal them in finder and lock the folder?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove these google apps from your Chrome Apps section. This will disable it from being installed after a Chrome update.

1. Open `chrome://apps/` on your browser.
2. Right Click on the App icon

[image]

3. Click "Remove from Chrome"
4. Repeat this action for all the Chrome apps that you do not want in the Launchpad section.

Comment: I've tried to do it but they appear again after the next Chrome update

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same problem.

What I ended up doing: hiding the apps in the Finder, and moving the apps in Launchpad to a folder as to not see them.

macOS allows you to hide files and folders, but it's a function that's not exposed in Finder. You will need to go through the terminal:

```
sudo chflags hidden "/Applications/Google Docs"
```